# How to set domain to Plesk VPS?

Tags: dns, vps

I have a VPS with Odin Plesk 12.5 configured and setup with a domain (lets call it `domain.com`). Now I want `domain.com` to go to the servers website (dedicated IP). In Odin Plesk I can see the DNS settings under the domain, but now I need to change the DNS or Nameservers for the domain to Plesk so that Plesk can handle the DNS (hope this is correct?).

Now the problem I am having. I can change the DNS settings at the domain with the following options:

> A
>
> AAA
>
> CNAME
>
> MX
>
> NS
>
> TXT
>
> SRV
>
> SSHFP
>
> TLSA

But, I also have the option to change the Nameserver for the domain (here I can fill in the Gluerecords). Now I am really clueless what to fill in where. Should I just change the Nameservers (Gluerecords) so that Plesk takes over the DNS? Or should I do both so that DNS has an `A` records to the servers IP? Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Only needed to set the Nameservers to `ns1.domain.com` and `ns2.domain.com` and add the Gluerecords. Another (dumb) problem was that I was visiting the website at `http://domain.com` which was not set (only www one).